Difference between "ParamListener" and "auto_declare" when initialising parameters in ros2_control
I am creating a custom controller using ros2_control. Going through the source code of existing controllers, I found out that there are 2 ways to initialize parameters(the one defined in controller config .yaml file). I need to know the difference between the two techniques.
The initialization of parameters is done in "on_init()" function.
In the "diff_drive" controller, the "on_init()" is like:
controller_interface::CallbackReturn DiffDriveController::on_init()
{
  try
  {
    // Create the parameter listener and get the parameters
    param_listener_ = std::make_shared<ParamListener>(get_node());
    params_ = param_listener_->get_params();
  }
  catch (const std::exception & e)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Exception thrown during init stage with message: %s \n", e.what());
    return controller_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
  }

  return controller_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
}

In this the param_listner_ line which is using ParamListner is responsible for initializing the parameters.
But the same "on_init()" for "Example_7" ros2_control_demo available at https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control_demos/example_7/doc/userdoc.html, is using auto_declare for parameter initialization.
The "on_init()" for "Example 7" is:
controller_interface::CallbackReturn RobotController::on_init()
{
  // should have error handling
  joint_names_ = auto_declare<std::vector<std::string>>("joints", joint_names_);
  command_interface_types_ =
    auto_declare<std::vector<std::string>>("command_interfaces", command_interface_types_);
  state_interface_types_ =
    auto_declare<std::vector<std::string>>("state_interfaces", state_interface_types_);

  point_interp_.positions.assign(joint_names_.size(), 0);
  point_interp_.velocities.assign(joint_names_.size(), 0);

  return CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
}

What is the difference between the two?

ParamListener is needed if the generate_parameter_library is used, the example you have linked just don't use it and the parameters are handled (and declared) manually.

Is it necessary to implement odometry and transforms when writing a custom controller or will the robot_state_publisher handle it? I never need to look into odometry as robot_state_publisher publishes odom and transforms automatically but i saw they are implemented explicitly specifically in diff_drive_controller.

robot_state_publisher does not calculate any odometry, it only takes joint_states and creates the tf tree with the given robot_description.
If you have a mobile robot, you will need to calculate its location in the world frame somehow.

I need to ask multiple such questions regarding ros2_control whose answer is most likely one liner. would it be better to create separate RSE Questions or should I ask them here only?

create separate RSE Questions please. And click "Accept this answer" if questions are solved.
